# How to query indexes in mongodb using the C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following data structure:

```
{
   eventname: "blah",
   invitees: [
     {
        inviteid: 1,
        userid: 34234
     },
     {
        inviteid: 2,
        userid: 5232
     }]
}
```

I am going to use `ensureIndex` on my invitees column so i do not have to search through every document to find specific userids in the invitees column.  Its basically searching for events that a specific userid was invited to.  I was suggested to use this `db.events.find({"invitees.userid" : 34234})` to query it, but how do i do this in c# with then 10gen driver.  the `.find` method only accepts a Mongo Query object.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I'm doing it is:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<MyType>("collectionName");
var query = Query.EQ("fieldname", valueToQuery);
var results = collection.Find(query);
```

Comment: Once you create the index on the column you can just query normally and it does everything for you?

Comment: Yes. You can use the .explain() command to verify the index, if any, that is used in a query

Comment: That's correct. You don't have to do anything to cause it to use the index. If you don't see the benefit you're expecting from the index, using the explain command as sambomartin mentioned above will show the index being used if one is used.